# SliverFillRemaining with Expanded and TabBarView

Tags: flutter, mobile

Why when I use the TabBarView as child of Expanded to fill all the height of the screen as follows

```
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      Expanded(child: Text('1')),
      Expanded(child: Text('1'))
    ],
  ),
)
```

it cause this error

> RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

When I remove the TabBarView, it still works.

I want the TabBarView to take all the height available with Expanded.
The Expanded is children of Column/SliverFillRemaining/CustomScrollView.             hasScrollBody: true makes it works but when i click to TextFormField, it cause overflow because the page can't be scroll

Comment: why not make the page scrollable? Its the only way to avoid overflow. Some users could have smaller devices so avoiding overflow on your specific test device does not solve the bigger issue

Answer (score 0):

give some height to the TabBarView

```
 Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: [
    Expanded(child: Text('1')),
    Expanded(child: Text('1'))
  ],
),
),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Expanded from children of tab bar view.

```
Expanded(child: TabBarView(
  controller: _tabController,
  children: const [
      Text('1'),
      Text('1'),
  ],
 ),
)
```

And for text field issue set hasScrollBody: false, fillOverscroll: true ,and wrap Column with SizedBox with height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,